I have an issue with the android SDK
So I recently got a meta quest 3s, and I am trying to make a game for it. I have made one in Unity, but when i export the APK and put it into the Meta Quest Devloper Hub app, i just get the error
Android Target SDK version is 30, but should be 32 or greater (targetSdkVersion in AndroidManifest.xml).
I really need help fixing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Didn't the error message said you should build your project targeting SDK version 32?

@FerryTo yes, it did. Is there any way I can do that in unity?

Doing a quick google search will lead you to configure Android studio, you should update your installed SDK.

Alright, thank you

Option 1: you can update Unity to the version, that is being shipped with needed Android SDK version. There is a page with info about this https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-sdksetup.html
Option 2: Download Android SDK manually. It shipped with Android Studio by default. You can download it here https://developer.android.com/studio#command-tools. After you will do this, you need to find android sdk folder inside Android Studio directory. There is a topic about it Android Studio SDK location. After you did this, you have to specify this path in Edit > Preferences > External Tools > SDK(Windows) or Unity > Settings > External Tools > SDK(Mac). Disable Android SDK Tools installed with Unity checkbox to specify custom path.
After you install required SDK, ensure you have needed version specified in
File > Project Settings > Player > Android tab > Other Settings > Target API Level
